# Can't suggest edits on Meta

Tags: support, editing, meta

I can suggest edits on main but not on meta. "edit" is grayed out and not available. Is there a restriction due to low reputation?

Comment: Maybe? :) What does the system say about required rep in this case?

Comment: @JosephWeissman the system just grays out "edit". I haven't found anything in the help center...and 500 doesn't also seem to be not enough as one of my other accounts shows.

Comment: `/help/privileges/` should lay out the required rep for these things.

Comment: @JosephWeissman http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges doesn't help at all...

Comment: that would be http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges of course :)

Comment: Oh, hmm -- I see. Well, keep in mind meta is a bit different...

Comment: @JosephWeissman and beta meta even more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one thought would be that edits on meta don't really have the same meaning as editing a question or answer on the mainpage. And of course you always can request somebody make their post CW if you think it could really benefit from community input. Otherwise comments/answers are probably the way to participate in generating consensus around things on meta.

Comment: I agree, so even you can't edit meta posts?

Comment: No, I can -- but that may just be diamond magic... I'd be curious whether other high-rep users can do this (it may be part of the 'trusted user' privilege which kicks in at 4k.)